# How to code shell '&' in C code?

Tags: c, shell, unix, exec, fork

After a long time of researching for my problem, I have really no idea how I can solve it. 
My question is that I need the C source code for something like this:

`ls &`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(void) {
    int new_pid;
    int status;

    new_pid = fork();

    if (new_pid == 0) {
        execlp("ls", "ls", "-l", NULL);
    } else {
        waitpid(new_pid, &status, 0);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If I code it like this, 'ls -l' will be executed, but it wasnt forked to the background.

It is just an example 'ls -l', it could also be 'xournal &;', 'libreoffice &' or something like this.
My main problem is that I have no idea how to code '&' in C.
Can anyone please provide me a tip or even a solution for this?

Comment: It's `<shift> + 7` on an American keyboard.

Comment: There are many example of programs using `fork` and the `exec` family of functions if you just search for it.

Comment: @H2CO3 `<shift> + 6` on Swedish keywords. :)

Comment: Google `fork()` system call.

Comment: Glad that you don't have to code `:(){ :|:& };:`

Answer (score 2):

When you execute another program, you need to call these functions:

```
new_pid = fork();
exec(...); //in the child only
```

If you want to wait until that new process ends (i.e. not specifying the `&` ) you call

```
waitpid(new_pid, ...);
```

That way, your shell blocks until the process you launced is finished.

If you don't want to wait, but just continue operating your shell (i.e. specifying the `&`) you simply do not call waitpid().

Answer (score 0):

Use `system("ls &")`.

It'd help if you explained why you wanted to run something in the background.